# Is it possible to insert an element into a middle of array in YAML using YQ?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a YAML document like this

```yaml
    
services:
  - name: newlogd
    image: NEWLOGD_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/newlogd
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: edgeview
    image: EDGEVIEW_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/eve-edgeview
    oomScoreAdj: -800
  - name: debug
    image: DEBUG_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/debug
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: wwan
    image: WWAN_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/wwan
    oomScoreAdj: -999
```

I need to insert a new object AFTER given element e.g. with name == "edgeview". so the output looks like this

```yaml
services:
  - name: newlogd
    image: NEWLOGD_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/newlogd
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: edgeview
    image: EDGEVIEW_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/eve-edgeview
    oomScoreAdj: -800
  - name: new_element_name
    image: new_element_image
  - name: debug
    image: DEBUG_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/debug
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: wwan
    image: WWAN_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/wwan
    oomScoreAdj: -999
```

I couldn't find anything about it in YQ documentation. Is it even possible using YQ?

**UPDATE:** I'm using YQ  https://github.com/mikefarah/yq version 4.28.1. I was not aware that there several tools with the same name.

Comment: Which version of yq are you using. Please update the question with that. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the YAML processor [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq):

```bash
yq --arg insertAfter edgeview -y '
   limit(1; .services | to_entries[] | select(.value.name == $insertAfter) | .key + 1) as $idx
   | .services |= .[0:$idx] +
                  [{name: "new_element_name", image: "new_element_image"}] +
                  .[$idx:]'
```

In the first line, the index of the element to be inserted after is determined and stored into `$idx`.
If you have several elements with the same name, only the first match is used (`limit`).
In the following filter step, `$idx` is used to split the array and insert the new element at the desired position.

**Output**

```yaml
services:
  - name: newlogd
    image: NEWLOGD_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/newlogd
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: edgeview
    image: EDGEVIEW_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/eve-edgeview
    oomScoreAdj: -800
  - name: new_element_name
    image: new_element_image
  - name: debug
    image: DEBUG_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/debug
    oomScoreAdj: -999
  - name: wwan
    image: WWAN_TAG
    cgroupsPath: /eve/services/wwan
    oomScoreAdj: -999
```

Comment: After switching to yq from this answer I could accomplish all tasks i need. I had to slightly change other queries because syntax is slightly different. I find Python based YQ syntax much more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Both implementations have their advantages and limitations.
It's good to know both if you work with json / yaml more often.
But this task I could not solve with [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/),
because of an [error](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1419) in splicing arrays I discovered.

Answer (score 2):

In the mikefarah/yq (v.4.30+) you can do:

```bash
yq '.services |= (
    (.[] | select(.name == "edgeview") | key + 1) as $pos |
    .[:$pos] + 
    [{"name": "new_element_name", "image": "new_element_image"}] +
    .[$pos:])' examples/data1.yaml
```

Explanation:

- You want to update the 'services' array, so we have '.services |= '
- Find the position to update the array in, which is one after then one with name "edgeview". Splat the array, find the matching entry, get its index and add one `(.[] | select(.name == "edgeview") | key + 1)`
- Assign the value of that position to $pos.
- Now you can use the array slice operator to reconstruct the array with the new element.
- Add the start of the array, `[:$pos]` with the new element `{"name": "new_element_name"}` to the end of the array `[$pos:]`

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: Thank you for the answer! yq is a great tool and as [@jpseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16332641/jpseng) said it is worth knowing both. Unfortunately there is not way to accept 2 answers here. After some time playing with both I ran for python wrapper version for one reason: it has --arg option that allows me to provide a named argument without using env() which I find a bit inconvenient especially when running yq  container from shell script